# What is model in MVC ? ASP.NET and repository pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, repository

Lately im reading a lot about MVC. 
Once and for all I want to know what model is (how you define it). 
Is that only a model class (e.g. when I am using EF it have a dbContext of course) ?

What if I am using Repository pattern ? Is model: 
-model class 
-repository and service ?
Can I name it all as model ?

Comment: Model it's all about data. You can create EF classes, service proxy classes,repo and etc. And use it as a model.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a house as example you could say:

The House itself is the Model which has just information about which color it has and out of which components (objects) it consists. 
It has the color blue and a door-object and a window-object etc. 
It doesn't need to know all about the functionality of a door, so it just has information about itself and its components.
The Door itself is a class too and knows how to open/close itselfe. It knows if it's opened or closed. So it contains a state => it's a Model too.

The house as a whole for example in a GUI-Representation in your Program is the View. If you want to interact with it in any way you could click on the doorhandle. The View will then call the Controller and tell him that you clicked on the doorhandle and he should take the according actions. So the View could be described as "the graphical representation of the Date (the Model/s)".

The Controller contains all the functionality to interact with one or more models at the same time. For example after it was called by the view because you clicked on the doorhandle it tells the door-class to open or close itself and tells the "lights"-class to turn on or off. 
So it knows more about the different components (models) and "controls" them.